# How to store a reference in boost::variant<T> instead of copying the object?

Tags: c++, boost, variant, boost-variant

Suppose I have a `boost::variant` defined as `boost::variant<Point, Line, Circle> shape`. Now if I make an object of the Point class, `Point p` and store it in shape as `shape = p` what I'm doing here is making a copy of p. How do I actually store a reference to p such that when I call `boost::apply_visitior(visitor, shape)` the visitor mutates not just the Point stored in the variant but also `p` itself?

Comment: You can't, or change your shape to allow reference too.

Answer (score 0):

```
boost::variant<Point*, Line*, Circle*>
```

then

```
shape = &p;
```

then have your visitor overload on pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a reference in `variant` (see the [`std::variant` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which explicitly spells that out but `boost::variant` is very similar) since a reference is just another name for a variable. `variant` is a fancy implementation of `union`. In both cases the value is stored *inside* the `union`/`variant`. Getting your object in there might come at the cost of a copy.

For small objects I wouldn't worry about the copy. If your objects are large and you need to avoid the copy you might want to consider using pointers instead:

```
boost::variant<Point*, Line*, Circle*> shape;
shape s = &p;
```

With pointers you might even decide to implement this using a traditional polymorphic approach rather than using `variant` (define an abstract class `shape` that `Point`, `Line`, and `Circle` inherit from and make `s` a pointer of the parent type:

```
shape s = &p;
```

Note that [the latter can be more error prone than using `variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.motivation.problem).